# How to raise the position of header?

Tags: header-footer

As I mentioned earlier that some of the chapters of my thesis is published papers which are embedded as pfd pages. These published papers have their own headers. As a chapter in thesis, I have also added a header for that chapter. These two headers sometimes remain in the same line and I want to raise chapter header. How should I do that? I shall appreciate to have a solution of this problem.

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,nogin]{book} 
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=1cm} \pagestyle{headings} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} 
\noindent \includepdf[page=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\section*{Brucellosis in small ruminants}\hfill}]{Smallruminant.pdf}:
```

this command made the above problem –

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem. Furthermore, the solution may depend on how you are defining the headings.  From the `layout` package it appears that those are controlled by `\topmargin` and `\voffset`, so you could try adjusting those.

Comment: \documentclass[oneside,english,nogin]{book}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=1cm}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\noindent \includepdf[page=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\section*{Brucellosis in small ruminants}\hfill}]{Smallruminant.pdf}: this command made the above problem

Comment: Hi, code blocks in comments aren't working. You can easily edit your original question. The edit-button is to the left of your user name. Makes it much easier for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the page geometry. If this is a good idea, depends on the use case.

[image: anisurPdfpagesHeaders]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-paper.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{Wombat}
\blindtext[30]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\newgeometry{headsep=1cm}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{headings}}]{\jobname-paper.pdf}
\end{document}
```